# Org Latex preview produces empty box when I use a certain package, how can I debug the issue?

Tags: org-mode, latex

The following line in my org file is causing problems

```
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{prooftrees}
```

If this line is there, then org latex preview produces an empty box.
If I remove it, things work just fine.

The output of *Org Preview LaTeX Output* is:

```
This is dvipng 1.17 Copyright 2002-2015, 2019 Jan-Ake Larsson
[1]
```

so I can't tell what's going wrong.
Finally, the *Messages* buffer only says: "Creating image...done", which doesn't help me understand why it's failing.

I know that the prooftrees package works, because I can get it to work in my normal latex compilation, so this seems to be a problems specifically with emacs org-mode.

How can I troubleshoot this issue? How can I see what latex it's generating and what commands it's running to produce the image?

Thanks

Edit:
The issue was with dvipng: this program would output a messed up png after processing the output dvi file. I tried changing to imagemagick but got a mysterious error. Changing to dvisvgm fixed the issue, so I guess this program is somehow better at processing dvi files that contain prooftrees.

To change to dvisvgm I did

- M-x customize-variable ENTER org-preview-latex-default-process
- then changed the value to "dvisvgm"

To catch the temporary tex files before emacs deleted them I used the following shell command in the /tmp directory:

```
inotifywait -mr --format '%w%f' -e create . | while read file; do if echo "$file" | grep '^./orgtex.*\.tex$' > /dev/null; then echo "file: $file"; cp $file ${file}.bkp; fi; done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preview code writes a TeX file into the `/tmp` directory with a name like `orgtexXXXXXX.tex` - there should also be a log file with name `orgtexXXXXXX.log`. Check the log file for errors and peruse the tex file to see if there are any obvious problems. Depending on your setting of `org-preview-latex-default-process`, the tex file may go through a different set of commands to get the final image. The default value is `dvipng` I believe, although `imagemagick` and `dvisvgm` are also possible. Check `org-preview-latex-process-alist` to see which path is actually taken.

For `dvipng`, the (simplified) commands are

```
latex orgtexXXXXXX.tex
dvipng orgtexXXXXXX.dvi
```

For `imagemagick` they are:

```
pdflatex orgtexXXXXXX.tex
convert orgtexXXXXXX.pdf orgtexXXXXXX.png
```

I've omitted all options on the "simplified" commands. The alist contains all the options, but you probably don't need them to debug your problem.

Comment: I would be interested to find out exactly what the problem was: can you add a comment (or edit your question) ad describe the resolution? Thanks!

Comment: Just added an edit. Thanks for the help, and let me know if you want any more details.

Comment: Thank you for the edit.